# CSS code in HTML no effect

Tags: html, css

I write the code in Notepad and execute by Chrome, but I don't see the color appaear,

[image: http://i.imgur.com/RJHb2Xp.png]

it seems that the CSS part of code doesn't take effect, what should I do to let the CSS part take effect?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>TITLE</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {background:white; color:black}
            a:link {color:red}
            a:visited {color:green }
            a:active {color:blue}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>B blue T Black</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this one:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>css</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {background-color:white; }

h1 
{
color:red;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body >

        <h1>B blue T Black</h1>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thanks, I run and success

Answer (score 5):

`<h1>` is not an `<a href="">` so none of your `a:` styles will apply, only `body { color: black; }` will be applied, that's why your text is black.

Replace your `a:` rules with a single `h1` rule or replace the `<h1>` with `<a href="#">`.

Comment: I'm reading a book at the begin so I don't see h1 yet, but I see it in other chapters, Thanks!

Comment: Before learning CSS I suggest you to learn HTML first. It's the code like `<h1>Biggest possible header</h1>` which has some default CSS-styles applied to it. After you know when to use what object, you could learn to style the object with CSS. `h1 { color:red }` for example then makes the text-color red. This way you don't get so confused by CSS before actually knowing what objects to style. Just my 2 cents. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Your  header is not a link. Your CSS is set up properly, it's just that there are no links to be styled. Wrap your  tag with an  and you should be good to go!

Comment: Thanks for your answer!